# using dropdownlist without postback for filling textboxes

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, postback

Hello i got a drop down list with post back from worker data base .
I also got a grid view with that data base.
when i choose a worker on the drop down i got 5 text boxes that are being filled from the right row on the grid view.
My question is how can i do that without using the auto post back?

p.s I am using visual studio with vb.net

Thanks in advance!

atm i am using something like this but i am really trying to remove all not needed postbacks from my site.

```
Protected Sub workerDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles workerDropDownList.SelectedIndexChanged


    Dim x As Integer
    For x = 0 To workerDataGrid.Rows.Count - 1
        If workerDataGrid.Rows.Item(x).Cells(1).Text = workerDropDownList.SelectedValue Then
            editWorkerNameBox.Text = workerDataGrid.Rows.Item(x).Cells(0).Text
            editWorkerIdBox.Text = workerDataGrid.Rows.Item(x).Cells(1).Text
            editPhoneBox.Text = workerDataGrid.Rows.Item(x).Cells(2).Text
            editCellPhoneBox.Text = workerDataGrid.Rows.Item(x).Cells(3).Text
            editEmailBox.Text = workerDataGrid.Rows.Item(x).Cells(4).Text
            editUserNameBox.Text = workerDataGrid.Rows.Item(x).Cells(5).Text
            editUserPassBox.Text = workerDataGrid.Rows.Item(x).Cells(6).Text
            editIsManagerBox.Text = workerDataGrid.Rows.Item(x).Cells(8).Text
            editIsActiveBox.Text = workerDataGrid.Rows.Item(x).Cells(7).Text


       End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Try with `Update Panel`

Comment: Try Using Jquery ajax function with [WebMethod] attribute to fill textboxes.